# Meteor - collection2 autoValue - how to access other document attributes that are not within the modifier

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

Let's say I'm generating an autoValue for an attribute of a document that I'm updating. However, I need one (or more) of the attributes of the existing document, which I don't have access to in the autoValue function.

For example:
I am generating an autoIncrement value for the document. I need the doc.company and doc.date attributes to calculate it. However, I'm only updating, let's say the doc.isFinished attribute. Thus, the doc.date is not accessible via this.field().

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Give us some code, share what you've tried, point us the error. Simple :)

Comment: I'll try again: let's say I have a document that has 10 fields. I run

Collection.update(myId, {$set: {name: 'my new name'});

This collection has a field called "autoincrement" which has a autoValue function assigned. However, with the above update, for example this.field('description') is undefined (because it's not in the $set) even though the document already has a description attribute which is not undefined.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what the `this.field` method is for, but note that you should be passing `field` to it, **not** `doc.field`.  For example:

```
YourCollectionSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    ...
    autoIncrement: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            var company = this.field('company').value,
                data = this.field('data').value;
            return // WHATEVER YOU NEED TO CALCULATE THE VALUE OF autoIncrement
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Obviously this might not fit your exact requirement, but should demonstrate how you get the value of other fields in autoValue.  If this kind of setup doesn't work for you then please paste your code, because it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Nice catch on `this.field('yourFieldName').value`  Did I miss that in the aldeed documentation?